# Highcharts series and categories not adding dynamically from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on the highchart.I came across a problem where the categories data  and series data which I am loading dynamically is not showing up. Here is my code.

```
    function loadChart() {              
        var categories = [];    
        var trend_series = [];
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
        url : '/trends.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : 'false',
            data: { date: d, item_name: item },
        success: function( data ) {
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            categories.push( key );
            trend_series.push( parseFloat( val ) );
            });
            },
        error: function( data ) {               
            //alert(data['responseText']);
        }
        });

        $( function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'line'                    
               },                           
           xAxis: {
              categories: {}
           },

               series: [{
              data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
           }]
             });

             chart.xAxis[0].setCategories( categories );
            chart.addSeries({
            name: 'App Summary',
            data:  trend_series       
            });
         });
        }
```

I am calling the `loadChart()` from another file.

One of the main problem which I notice that the categories and trend_series (these are arrays )is empty inside the highchart function . But it is not empty inside the ajax function call. How can I pass those values to highchart function or is there any other method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the categories and the data but the chart has no way to be notified of that.
You need to do categories.push() and then redo `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories,true)` again, and same with the data, `chart.series[0].setData(trend_series,true)` in your success function in the ajax call.
The `true` option triggers the chart.redraw()

Comment: thank you for replying. I have tried with the your solution. Inside ajax success function I added this two lines of code              var chart = new Highcharts.Chart();    
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories,true);chart.series[0].setData(trend_series,true);    .. Already I am pushing the categories value into categories array.  After this also it is not working .Let me know if this is not correct.

Comment: can you do some console.log for chart, categories and trend_series? the way you declared things in the example above seems a bit incorrect as you have a jquery initialization call inside a function. Normally it would be the opposite. a jsfiddle would be good.

Comment: when I do a console.log(categories) inside the ajax sucess function, it is giving result(I mean values). But when I do the same console.log(categories) inside highchart function, it is showing empty array. Is there any way to pass that variable to highchart function.Already I declared the variable as global.

Comment: Is there any way to load the highchart function after the ajax success function is completed?

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating the chart inside the success function. Especially if you're only creating the graph once. Inside success call the whole highchart function as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this  solution even though it is bit wierd,

I moved the enitre highchart function to another function. On ajax success function I am calling the next function `renderChart()` . The code is as follows.

```
function loadChart() {              
      categories = [];    
      trend_series = [];

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
        url : '/trends.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : 'false',
            data: { date: d, item_name: item },
        success: function( data ) {
            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            categories.push( key );
            trend_series.push( parseFloat( val ) );
            });
            renderChart(categories,trend_series);
            },
        error: function( data ) {               
            //alert(data['responseText']);
        }
        });
        }
```

To load highchart

```
      function renderChart(categories,trend_series){
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'line'                    
               },                           
           xAxis: {
              categories: {}
           },

               series: {}
           }]
             });

             chart.xAxis[0].setCategories( categories );
            chart.addSeries({
            name: 'App Summary',
            data:  trend_series       
           });   
  }
```

Comment: Yes, that's how should this work - when data comes from AJAX - create chart. You can also upgrade code - use: `categories: categories` and serieS: [{ name:'app Summary', data: trend_series }]` when creating chart instead of using setCategories and addSeries.

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you use

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
        url : '/trends.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async : 'false',
            data: { date: d, item_name: item },
        success: function( data ) {

var options = {
   chart: {
              renderTo: 'container',
              type: 'line'                    
               },                           
           xAxis: {
              categories: []
           },
    series:{
data:[]
}

}

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            options.xAxis.categories.push(key);
            options.series.data.push( parseFloat( val ) );
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            },
        error: function( data ) {               
            //alert(data['responseText']);
        }
        });
```